# Is it necessary to pay extra for navigation when renting a car in the US?

Tags: usa, car-rentals, gps-navigation

This is a relatively straightforward question. I'm scheduled to visit the US in a couple of weeks. It's been around 15 years since I've been there, and I don't remember much as my parents had taken care of most of the work back then.

I want to rent a car in Las Vegas so that I can drive to the Grand Canyon and back. I noticed that they have an option to pay extra to add a GPS system. Is this necessary? I suppose the reason I'm asking is because (at least in my home country of Korea) everyone uses their phones and navigation apps (e.g. Google Maps, Kakao Maps, T-Map, etc.)

Are there any details that I'm unaware of that may cause adding on the navigation to be more beneficial? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Worth noting, that frequently these days even if you choose not to pay for GPS, the car comes with it anyway - although the hire company may of course not have provided complete/updated maps for it.

Comment: define necessary

Comment: You can also brave it like the pioneers and use paper maps. :-)  Once you are on interstate 40, the exit numbers will tell you where you are.

Comment: Rental companies are like AOL... even after the product is obsolete they sell it anyway as long as they can... At one time, separate nav units were useful since it wasn't in every single phone, but unless you are time traveling from 2002, there is absolutely no reason for anyone to get this service.

Comment: I remember driving a car from NY to LA in the 1970s, with a group of Brit friends.  At the time there were agencies who arranged to get students like ourselves to drive cars for people moving from east to west.  I can assure you that you won't have the slightest difficulty finding your way from Las Vegas to the Grand Canyon and back and will need neither GPS nor offline maps.

Comment: Always ask if the car has GPS built in. I've been asked if I wanted to pay extra for GPS, said no, and then found the car came with GPS. When I pointed this out the rep said that if I said yes they would have charged me. That's what management had told them to do.

Comment: I found when we went that it was cheaper to buy a worldwide satnav (that I still have) that to rent one from them for 10 days

Comment: Incidentally, I doubt there's anywhere in the world where it's cheaper to rent a satnav than buy one from a local store - but in my experience, phone software works just fine.

Comment: @CMaster - I usually rent a car one or twice a month and have rarely found a rental car with built-in navigation. They pretty much all have a touch screen and the capability for navigation, but finding a car that has it activated is rare. Even Android Auto or Apple Car play functionality is not guaranteed. So I always plan on using my phone for navigation and am happily surprised if the car supports Android Auto... though eve in cars that support navigation, I usually use my phone for the live-traffic updates and voice control that I'm used to.

Comment: @GrandmasterB And where exactly do you buy those paper maps? I recently tried to get one at a gas station - in Germany, though - and my request was met with blank stares, only.

Comment: @I'mwithMonica pretty much the same here in the US. Few people can use a paper map anymore, and even fewer paper maps are available.

Comment: Most hotel lobbies have a rack of brochures advertising local attractions.  You'll almost certainly find one for the Grand Canyon, and it should include a map and directions from Vegas.  No matter what you do regarding digital maps, I highly recommend that you grab one of these on your way out as a backup.

Comment: @I'mwithMonica Most convenience stores in the US still sell road atlases.  That may vary by chain, and of course small independent gas stations may not carry them. You can also get them at Walmart, book stores, etc.  Our local Barnes and Noble has a big section of atlases and maps for all over the world.  Also, a lot of highway rest stops & welcome centers (at state borders) offer free maps of the state.  They aren't nearly as depreciated as some people think.   Plus don't forget, as bta mentioned, asking the hotel front desk.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have a modern phone, you don't need to rent the GPS with the car. Just install a navigation app that supports offline maps (this includes Google Maps these days but there are others), and download the proper maps in advance. I usually have a second app as backup.

The only minor inconvenience is that you need a mount (I use a cheap generic one bought at a dollar store) and have the charger cable in the car to keep the phone connected. Any car you rent (with possibly the exception of a very cheap compact) will have a usb port to plug it in.

As mentioned in the comments, it is important to have offline maps anyway, since it is unlikely to have cell coverage in the area of the Grand Canyon. As an example, here is the coverage by AT&T (blue is LTE, green is other AT&T, yellow is roaming):

[image]

Comment: The offline maps part is important to stress, as you might not have cell coverage in that part of the US for significant amounts of time. Obviously depending on your carrier and your actual route.

Comment: When buying a car recently, they didn't have any vehicles in the lot with GPS. The salesperson told me that was because no one wanted to pay a couple thousand dollars more for something they can do on their phone for free.

Comment: @GrandmasterB modern cars now have Apple/Android auto which accomplishes the task much better

Comment: @JonathanReez Yes, thats what I have been using on the rare occasions I need GPS.  Works very well and displays right on the car's display.

Comment: It would pay to look up the rules for using handheld devices in the jurisdictions you plan to visit: most (all?) states have strict rules (with varying enforcement) against using handled devices while you drive. At the very least you'll need to have it mounted in a holder of some kind. Of course, if there will be a passenger who can handle the device, there's no problem.

Comment: @CCTO There are also places like California that don't allow things to be mounted on the windscreen

Comment: Or you know, just buy a printed map for a few dollars at the local gas station or a bookstore. I always have those in my car because you never know when coverage might just disappear on an interstate. As an aside, i imagine there is always enough traffic between LV and the Grand Canyon that there is good coverage all along the route... Barring really bad weather like in winter.

Comment: Most cell phone companies only cover urban America, and roam onto AT&T or Verizon for the more remote places, which are the only two companies that really make an effort to cover rural areas.  If AT&T is roaming, that's poor coverage indeed.

Comment: Rural areas may or may not be covered, yes. But interstate highways and narrow bands around them are much better covered than expected. I have done lots of driving through the West and I drive through Arizona and CA like three times a year. The only place that I can remember losing a signal was in Wyoming (I-80) and East Utah (I-70) and even then it was a few years ago so it might be better by now AND it was never a problem at all because you only need a coarse set of directions most of the time until you get to a large town/city and need to get somewhere specific.

Comment: "Leave Vegas going East/North on I-15. In the middle of Utah somewhere take I-70 East. In Denver take I-25 South. From Albuquerque take I-40 West and stop in Flagstaff." That's all you need for a 1,500 mile drive. You pull over for the next motel, gas station, or a fast food joint and then get back on the road. In a small town, you exit and go down main street and/or ask locals and you will most likely find whatever it is you are looking for. To get to the freeway from a random part of the city in LV or Flagstaff is where you may need navigation but then again, those places are well-covered.

Comment: I just stare at the map for a few minutes before leaving for the trip. I use google map in a large city, or if I need to search for something specific like the closest pharmacy from me in Phoenix, or if I just want to see how many miles I have traveled and how many are remaining and what's the estimated time of arrival, etc. You don't really need the map apps unless you start taking smaller roads and shortcuts or entering/exiting an unfamiliar city including the termini cites for your trip.

Comment: How well will offline maps work in an area with no cell coverage at all?  I know you can look at the maps, so what I really mean is: how well will the phone's GPS work?  Is it really GPS off of satellites?  I thought phones had only time-of-flight from cell towers? (Which stack would be an appropriate place for this question?)

Comment: Offline maps work well because cell phones have different antennas for cell coverage and for GPS. So yes, GPS does talk directly with the satellites and also GPS antennas are not turned off in airplane mode (at least on my android). It is absolutely fantastic how much power you can save by using the airplane mode. So what I do is before starting the trip download the maps, start the trip on google maps with my GPS turned on. Then as soon as I leave the city I turn on airplane mode while keeping GPS on. So my position is still updated on the map in real time.

Comment: I have made it from ABQ to LA on a 13 hour trip using only 40%-50% of my battery without any charging.

Comment: Offline maps aren't just important because of lack of coverage (applies for the specifics of visiting the Grand Canyon) but also because of the potentially high cost of using mobile data when abroad.

Answer (score 12):

I'm going to add a 3rd option.  Buy your own stand-alone GPS unit from a big box store in the US.  Depending on how long your trip is, what data plan you have for your phone, or how much the GPS rental is from the car company this *may* be a cheaper option.

Additional benefits of this option is that the device will come with mounting hardware, and that when your trip is over you can sell the device and re-coup some/most of your costs.

The downside to this is that the maps in the device may not be the most up to date and that you'd be looking many gigabytes of downloads for the latest maps.  But in general for a trip around Nevada to tourist destinations you will most likely not need the very latest maps.

Comment: If you buy a used stand-alone GPS unit off of eBay or at a local pawn shop, you might even be able to sell it for roughly what you paid for it.

Comment: There is no way you can buy an item from a pawn shop, walk out the door, walk back in and expect to sell it for the same price you paid.  Your local pawn shop is going to buy stuff at some percentage of what they can sell it for - that's simple business practice.  You might sell for the same price on eBay - but I wouldn't expect it.

Comment: You definitely won't be able to sell anything to a pawn shop for a good price.  I was thinking more like reselling it on ebay, craigslist, etc.  I've done that with small electronics before and essentially got several days of use for the price of shipping.  Significantly better than the rental car company rates.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't have mobile internet access while in the US you have to resort to offline maps or to the car GPS, because you can't download maps on your phone as you navigate.

I've rented a car in the US a couple of times and I always added a GPS, because the roaming costs for mobile internet connection are very high, and I didn't want to buy a US SIM card for a short trip. At home, and in the EU where there are no roaming costs, I use Google maps to navigate.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to take into account that connection in the US is not as well-established as it is in Korea. I suppose that if I were to have a device like a Wi-Fi Egg it should be okay?

Comment: You can also use a phone GPS which is not mobile connection based. I have bought one but there are also free ones around.

Comment: @Seankala I suppose so. Apparently there are some providers that offer rental of wifi eggs with sim card, you have to see what works best for you: paying for the wifi egg or the GPS.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that if you're driving in the middle of nowhere you won't get any phone signal, Wi-Fi Egg or no Wi-Fi Egg. Downloading maps in advance is really the only safe option.

Comment: And most of this proposed drive is in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: @Seankala It's well established, it's just that the US has a LOT more land with little population compared to South Korea.  The US has about 100x more land area and only about 5x the population of SK.  Equivalent land coverage is not economical - it would cost 20x more in infrastructure to have mobile coverage spread uniformly over the entire land mass.

Comment: @Muzer I'd also point out that "Driving in the middle of nowhere" can mean 2 miles off the main freeway depending on who your carrier is (I'm looking at you T-Mobile)

Comment: @Muzer: Another safe option besides downloading offline maps is to get paper maps — buy them, or print them yourself in advance.  Extra bonus: unlimited battery life.

Comment: @PLL Well, naturally, but my comment assumed someone who wouldn't touch paper maps with a barge pole, or someone who wants to be able to drive and navigate at the same time. Not everyone has a second person to sit in the car whose sole job is to read the maps and try to tell an increasingly frustrated driver where to go. Honestly, I'm glad those days are behind us.

Comment: @Muzer a little known fact: One can pull to the side of the road and stop while looking at a paper map. Source: Decades of personal experience from before GPS existed. Granted, there can be more frustration with this method, but it is _eminently_ doable!

Comment: @FreeMan at least where I live, you can't do that when you're on a motorway. The hard shoulder is for emergencies only - and nowadays there isn't one on many motorways! You're going to have to find a service station or a layby to stop in. I'm not saying it's physically impossible to use paper maps but it's so much easier while driving to use GPS-driven electronic maps that I'm surprised anyone but the most stubborn of individuals would advocate for them. Outdoors I can see it being different (but I'm not an outdoorsy kind of guy so I can't really comment).

Comment: @Muzer not sure where you live, but, "hard shoulder", "motorway", and "layby"  indicate UK. In the US, it's generally considered acceptable to stop on the shoulder of any road _except_ where explicitly signed that it's not allowed. Most cops would be quite happy to see you reading your map while stopped on the shoulder of the interstate instead of trying to read it while on the move (and would give you directions)! Navigating by paper map isn't a stubborn anti-tech stand (hey, I'm online for this forum!), but is a practical skill necessary for when the high-tech solution isn't available.

Comment: @FreeMan So, necessary never. Except when you haven't planned ahead by buying a car charger and downloading maps, at which point you also won't have a paper map since you're the sort of person not to plan ahead.

Comment: @J... Note, also, that the western United States contains the Rocky Mountains--they're young mountains and thus still pretty sharp--providing a lot of terrain shadowing.  The main highways normally have cell service but dead spots are common in the mountains, I'm aware of one that's something like 10 miles long 100 miles outside Las Vegas.

Answer (score 9):

Because Korea is extremely dense and that makes it easy to essentially 100% cover with cell phone service.  **The Grand Canyon has a vast wilderness, almost comparable to Siberia**.

### Whether a car sat-nav makes sense depends on the unit

A *traditional* Sat-Nav device (you mis-call them "GPS") has a huge amount of memory to store pre-programmed maps of your region. It also has a GPS receiver so it knows its coordinates.

However, obviously, the trend is to go to "cellular data connected" types, because they have the latest maps, do smarter routings based on collected data, and are able to adapt to live and past-pattern traffic conditions.  **These will be useless in many parts of the Canyon**.

Increasingly, the car rental agencies are likely to hand you a loose "device" that is basically an Android tablet, and rent that to you for some outlandish price.  Don't count on it being mounted, integrated, or audible in driving conditions.

It also depends on **the language**.

### Where's your brain-trust?

"Who is your English speaker?" vs "Who is your driver"?

Because the rental-car company supplied unit will be English language, almost certainly.  If *only the driver* speaks English well, this is a bad division of labor.  The rental company's choice of device will be unfamiliar and awkward. **To be clear, the person driving is not the person who should be dealing with the nav**. Messing with any smart device while driving is always dangerous; but an unfamiliar or balky one is *much more dangerous* because of how the brain responds to *unexpected* behavior.   Brains do not multi-task; they rapidly task-switch (badly).  Unexpected behavior from a balky device makes the brain *not switch back* at the expected time, extending the head-down time and making you crash.

**If there are 2 adults in the car, the driver should not be navigating** or interacting with electronic equipment.  The other person should.  Which means the nav aids need to be in that person's language.

Which brings us to the ideal division of labor on a long road trip.

### Driver drives. Navigator navigates. Navigator is always right.

The best division of labor on a road trip is 2 people: One person to drive and the other to navigate.  The driver treats the navigator's word as absolutely correct.  If the driver strongly feels otherwise, the driver pulls over safely to the side of the road and they look at the maps together and resolve it.  *The driver does not badger or argue with the navigator, or make the navigator afraid to speak freely.  The navigator does not give too-late or shaky/uncertain instructions; better to give a wrong instruction firmly, then at an appropriate time, a second instruction to correct the course**.  Once you get the rhythm of it, it works very well.

Obviously, that creates a language dependency.

A sat-nav *attempts to* automate the navigator's job. A human navigator is worlds better.  The human might use the sat-nav as a tool, *but would be better off using tools the navigator is already familiar with*.  I certainly would be reluctant to *reserve in advance* a Sat-nav the navigator has not had time to play with to see if it's a good fit.

If you are the English speaking driver, I'd rather you converse with the navigator in Korean and have the navigator use a familiar tool in Korean.  Google Maps is available on iOS and Android obviously, and allows pre-loading of offline maps.  It keeps them in memory only for 30 days or so, so don't load them too soon or it'll delete them.

### Paper maps are your friend

Really. There is no substitute for paper maps.  They are large, and present *both* the entire "big picture" *and also* the finer details.

However again, they need to be in the navigator's language.  Sourcing Korean language maps of the US Grand Canyon ... in the US ... may be a challenge; get them at home.

### The "Rescue Me" button

I mention this because this happens at least a couple times a year, usually in the winter.  People make wrong turns (often due to sat-nav telling them to), the car has a problem, and **they die out there**.  Every case could have been trivially solved with one piece of tech: **The 406 MHz ELT.**  This uses the military-grade, built-for-purpose distress signal system also used by jetliners and cruise ships.  Due to the high cost of the infrastructure (many satellites), there is one world system with all the major powers onboard.  A handheld beacon costs about $400 (once, no annual fee) and they can also be rented.  It has exactly one job. Break seal, push button, forget it, focus on survival, and 2-12 hours later, help appears.  It doesn't do anything else.  It works anywhere but the steepest canyons (and obviously not caves), but this time of year you should be staying out of slot canyons *anyway*.   If you have a mind to do anything slightly adventurous, or just if you're bad at navigation, think about getting one of these.

---

---

* Example.

"Continue straight here.  Do not get on the freeway."

"OK".

"At the next opportunity, do a U-turn.  We do need the freeway, after all.  I wasn't sure, and I called straight because it would be easier to recover."

"OK, good call."

"Get on the freeway northbound.  This ramp here, follow the brown truck".

Comment: I would add that the navigator shouldn't present the driver with choices, especially if the driver has no context from which to make decisions ("you can turn right here or go straight").  Also the driver has to be able to disregard the navigator's instructions when they are unsafe or illegal (for example, "turn right here" when the car is already in the left-turn-only lane).

Comment: +1 to everything in this excellent answer except “However again, they [paper maps] need to be in the navigator's language.”  Reading a map in a foreign language requires *much* less proficiency than following GPS system directions.  Provided the navigator can read English script enough to read and recognise place-names quickly, they should be fine with paper maps in Englis.  I’ve often navigated from maps in languages I don’t know.  There are usually only a few pieces of important text esides placenames (e.g. the key for road-type symbols), and those can be puzzled out in advance.

Comment: Second the warning about a lack of cell coverage.  People from dense areas expect their phones to always work--in the western United States if you're between cities and not on a major highway do not expect your phone to work--and even then there will be dead spots.  I have yet to see a cell tower in a national or state park, sometimes you get service from outside, most of the time you don't.

Comment: You are exactly correct about the paper maps.  The park service gives out very good quality maps of the park as you enter, and the parks have plenty of signage.  Maps in languages other than English are available as well (international tour groups are very common), ask a ranger about them as you enter.

Answer (score 7):

It mostly depends on what you would otherwise use for navigation. Also, consider that you are planning to travel to an area with a low population density (high risk of getting lost, as well as patchy cell coverage, see [Death by GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_by_GPS)).

Regarding your “usual” navigation options, consider:

- Is off-line navigation supported? You might not have a data connection, or it might be prohibitively expensive.
- Is off-line navigation **fully** supported? Some solutions calculate a route and cache the data, but if you need to recalculate your route without a data connection, you’re out of luck. To be on the safe side, opt for a solution where the map data is on the device, not in the cloud.
- How complete and up-to-date are the maps? (The same question applies to the device provided by the rental company.)
- What about the legality of using your cell while driving? More specifically:

  - Some legislations forbid looking at a screen while driving. Though that applies to a cell phone just as a sat-nav installed in the vehicle. The only option here is to have the front passenger do the navigation.
  - Some legislations forbid holding electronic devices while driving; a cell mount will solve this.
  - Some legislations forbid mounting devices on the windshield; a cell mount attached to a ventilation grille is your friend here.
  - Some legislations forbid interacting with electronic devices while driving (which might also apply to sat-nav devices installed in the car); either have a (savvy) passenger take care of this or pull over when you have to enter a new destination.

If you intend to rely on your cell, be sure to carry a car charger and cable for it. Not all rental cars may have a USB port, but a 12V plug is pretty much standard.

Answer (score 4):

If all you’re doing is going to the Grand Canyon and if you are comfortable getting out of the city without a GPS then the drive is very straightforward. There will be phone coverage within Las Vegas itself.

Worth noting cellphones in the US are very expensive compared to other countries.

Comment: The drive is straightforward **if** you don't make a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

We paid extra in the US recently and they gave us an android device that took us around in circles trying to get out of Los Vegas. Ended up using Google maps and forgot about the supplied one.

Won't be bothering with paying extra for GPS next time.

Note: we had T mobile SIM cards for mobile data and I'd also setup offline maps.

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly, though even cheap cars in the UK come with built-in satnav, I've never had a rental car in North America -- even upmarket models -- come with a built-in satnav.  And although I use a Samsung Galaxy phone and find its navigation useful when on foot in strange countries, even that size of screen isn't great while you're driving.  When I travel to North America I take a stand-alone satnav (with built-in American mapping) with me -- that way I get a good satnav for less than the cost of renting one for a couple of weeks -- and I have it when I need it most, driving away from the car-hire office!

Answer (score -1):

Buy a $5 map at a gas station. You will easily be able to navigate yourself to and from the Grand Canyon.

Comment: While the advice is good, the brevity make it look like a 'drive-by' answer, which is not the style here.  Yahoo Answers is a better fit for that style.  I do not downvote for that, but that is why you are getting DVs.